# Techniques for blocking domains in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, blocking, malware

Had a virus on an old Windows XP Pro (SP3) workstation we were given to dispose of that had been powered down for over a year. We were able to clean it up (Malware Bytes, SpyBot, Symantec, etc.), or so we thought.

Sniffing traffic on a hub doesn't reveal anything so it appears that the virus is indeed dormant and/or removed, nor is the workstation experiencing any other symptoms except that you cannot browse to *.microsoft.com, symantec.com, etc. from within Internet Explorer still.

Outside of the usual suspects -- proxy settings change in IE, hosts files, etc. -- where else could you restrict access with Internet Explorer? There doesn't appear to be any add-ons loaded, nor can we see any rogue processes running.

NOTE: we're not looking for another tool to run (i.e. combofix), but technical details on how/where these restrictions are implemented. i.e. hooks into the TCP/IP stack, registry keys, etc.

Comment: Try Firefox and Fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a central configuration point, you could also use your internal DNS server to mis-resolve domains. This works just like the `hosts` file, but it's centralized.

Comment: This is not a DNS issue: I can resolve domain names with nslookup on the machine. There's either a process running that we're not seeing (maybe a rogue svchost.exe) or a misconfiguration of Winsock, WinHTTP, or some other IE "internals" bit that we're not familiar with.

Comment: @gravy... OH! it's **already** being mis-resolved within IE... I thought you were asking how to prevent any traffic from going to that site in the future.

Comment: Yeah, it's more of a learning exercise right now: I want to know what ways you can misconfigure or hijack IE to prevent it from accessing certain domains.  hosts file or DNS is the first thing I check, also proxy settings, but this one is using something else.